# Не получается удалить Python 3.10 на ОС Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x

*Всем доброго времени суток! При установке Python 3.10 понял что обновляться еще не хочу (тк чайник в пайтоне) и решил удалить 3.10. Все файлы удалены (pip, idle и тд), но сам язык не удаляется из-за какой то ошибки:*

> **В процессе установки произошла неисправимая ошибка. Please fix the issues and then retry setup. For more information see the log file**

*Код ошибки: 0x80070643
Пожалуйста помогите ее исправить!*

Comment: Попробуйте запустить файл установки от имени администратора.

Answer (score 1):

Обновите [.NET Framework](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/topic/microsoft-net-framework-4-8-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-windows-9d23f658-3b97-68ab-d013-aa3c3e7495e0).

Или попробуйте еще раз почистить остаточные файлы от Python 3.10.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Духсообщества этот ответ очень даже понятен